# How can I pass a file path with %20 as an argument to a process?

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, process.start

I'm currently using C# to develop an app that will launch an app with given parameters (the app path and the document we're trying to open).

Here's the code I've tried so far:

```
var pi = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath)
{
        Arguments = "\"" + Path.GetFileName(filePath) + "\"",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath),
        FileName = appPath,
        Verb = "OPEN"
};
Process.Start(pi);
```

where `filePath` is the path to the file we want to open and `appPath` is the path of the app we want to open the file in (`C:\Program Files\...\POWERPNT.exe`).

This solution works for files with and without spaces, however it doesn't work for files with '%20', which refuse to open in apps like PowerPoint. Example below:

> "PowerPoint can't open this type of file (C:\...\...\Statistics Made Easy.ppt)."

On Windows Explorer, the name of the file is Statistics%20Made%20Easy.ppt. Note that %20 got replaced by a space in the error message. What could the issue be?

Comment: Spaces have nothing to do with it. You have problems with %20, which is %, 2 and 0, not a space.

Comment: @ThomasWeller yes, that's the issue (not spaces my bad). What could be the reason why PowerPoint is not opening the file?

Comment: The reason is probably that `filePath` contains spaces and not `%20`. The problem is probably before the code shown

Comment: @Adassko: It works with spaces. It does not work with %20

Comment: @ThomasWeller it looks like the file is named "Statistics%20Made" but he tries to open "Statistics Made"

Comment: @Adassko: if you reproduce it, you'll find that this is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to not set the working directory and use the full path for the file name instead:

```cs
var pi = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath)
{
        Arguments = "/ou \"" + filePath + "\"",                 // full path here
        UseShellExecute = false,
        // WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath),  // skip this
        FileName = appPath,
        Verb = "OPEN"
};
```

If Powerpoint is the default app to open PPT files, you can also use

```
Process.Start(filePath);
```

without specifying `pi` at all.
If the user changed the app to be used with PPT files, this might start a different app, of course.